# Partially transpose data which pasted as a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

When I paste data from certain applications, it ends up as:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
```

But it's supposed to be:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
```

Is there an easy way to restructure?

Comment: You should show some real data which you are copying or else people will focus too much on succeeding with simply `A B C D E F G H I J K L`. It would be in your best interest to also provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In below example, formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,ROW(A1)*4-4+COLUMN(A1))
```

[image]

Drag down and right...

Basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968780/how-to-transpose-column-in-several-rows-in-excel/55969041#55969041) answer on SO.

Note: You can change `*4-4` to any number of columns you want to transpose into > `*n-n`

Comment: Better add `IFERROR` to avoid error if no value! +10 ☺

Answer (score 3):

You can use this formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW(A1)-1)*4+COLUMN(A1)-1,)
```

[image]

Comment: ,, how to replace 0 with blanks,, formula returns when no value ?

Comment: Add **IF** function?